# Writing to CSV - Rows, not columns

Tags: python, csv

I am stuck on a problem where my script writes to multiple columns and not rows. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Disclosure - I am really new to programming.

EDIT - Figured it out. This worked :-)

Any thoughts?

```
import json
import csv
import subprocess
import urllib
import requests
from unidecode import unidecode

def main():
    list_writer= open_csv()
    info = test_method()
    for list in info:
        write_to_csv(list_writer, list)


def test_method():
    r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/legacy/repos/search/python'+'?start_page=1', auth=('user', 'pass'))
    dict_of_repos = json.loads(r.text)
    list_of_repos = dict_of_repos["repositories"]
    repo_information = []
    for repo in list_of_repos:
        indiv_repo = []
        indiv_repo.append(repo["name"])
        indiv_repo.append(repo["fork"])
        print indiv_repo
        repo_information.append(indiv_repo)
    return repo_information

def open_csv():
    github_csv = open('Githubcsv_1_2.csv', 'wb')
    writer = csv.writer(github_csv)
    return writer   

def write_to_csv(list_writer, info):
    list_writer.writerow(info)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: try narrowing your problem down a little more rather than giving us your whole program

Comment: maybe add a /n/r after each row? or some sort of breakline

Comment: Just scanning your code briefly, a `writerow` function normally means write one row of many columns. Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Isaac Well it is. I want to write a name to each row. Eventually, there will be more than just the name. But I am doing this for now to test it out.

Comment: a blank `return` is not required; and you really need to use the [`with` statement](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example) for your file operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like your `repo_information` will look like

```
[
  ['name'],
  ['name2'],
  ['name3']
]
```

so it looks like all you need is to [`writerows`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows)

```
def write_to_csv(list_writer, info):
    list_writer.writerows(info)
```

This, of course, will write all the data to one column (each name being on a seperate row).  If you want to write it all to the same row you could:

```
for repo in list_of_repos:            
        repo_information.append(repo['name'])
    print repo_information # ['name', 'name2', 'name3']
    return repo_information
```

and then `writerow` like you are currently doing. This would then put all the names in the same row.

Comment: I actually want to write them to different rows. So each repo name would be on its own row.